# Newtonsoft.JSON: JSON List and Array are handled differently

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Given the following code:

```
public class ColorList 
{
    public List<string> Colors = new List<string>(new string[1] { "#eeeeee"});
}
public class ColorArray 
{
    public string[] Colors = new string[1] { "#eeeeee"};
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string json = "{Colors:['#abc','#123']}";

        // Deserialize Colors into List:
        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ColorList>(json).Colors.Count);
        // returns 3
        // Deserialize Colors into Array:
        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ColorArray>(json).Colors.Length);
        // returns 2
    }
}
```

Why is there a difference between the two deserializations?

Comment: Sounds like it's adding to a list (because it can) but replacing the whole array (because it can't do anything else, although I guess it could copy the original values). If you just change your code so that a newly created object doesn't have any entries, you should be fine though.

Comment: I've tried your code and @JonSkeet seems to be right. In a List, is not a problem to add new values, but in a Array you must recreate it,as once it has a dimension it can't be (easily) redimensionated. Anyway, it is really an unexpected behaviour to me, as I would expect a new collection when deserialized.

Comment: Does it make sense that Serializer and Deserializer are not inverse functions? Can serializer and deserializer not being inverse be considered a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to Jon Skeet comment, want to add that you may partially control this behavior:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings() {
     ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace
};
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ColorList>(json, settings).Colors.Count); // returns 2, because list was replaced, not reused
```

However, even if you will use `ObjectCreationHandling.Reuse` with array - it will not reuse it, but still will replace (well it cannot really reuse it anyway).

Since you wrote that you would expect new collection when deserialized - that might help you.

Comment: I didn't know that Setting,thank you